# Does Azure Storage function object.DeleteIfExists() check for existence when it is Invoked?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, file-exists

Sounds like a silly question but with .Net System.IO.FileInfo.Exists, the class checks for existence when it is instantiated, so if another process creates a file of the same name in the same place in the interval between my process instantiating FileInfo and checking FileInfo.Exists, my process will get a false negative.

Do Azure Storage objects have the same wrinkle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. It sends deletion request to Azure Storage service directly, and swallows the exception if "(404) Not Found" happens.

Comment: Hi Lu, sorry, I though I responded earlier. Thanks very much for your answer.